# I can print data from API but i can't set values and UI with this data in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui

I sent data to my ListView, and can print it in console. The problem is that i can't update any values with this data, so can't also update UI with it.
My app should take a city name which String - put it to fetchWeather() func, download data and do all stuff, and after this start getWeather() func in in ListView and update values (city), which i use in UI.

Code:

WeatherMenager:

```
 import Foundation
    
    struct WeatherManager {
        
    
        let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=APP_ID&units=metric"
        
        func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
            let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
            performRequest(with: urlString)
            return
        }
        
        
        func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        
                        return
                    }
                    if let safeData = data {
                        if let weather = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                            
                            let listVC = ListView()
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                                listVC.getWeather(weather: weather)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }
        
        func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
                let id = decodedData.weather[0].id
                let temp = decodedData.main.temp
                let name = decodedData.name
                
                let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId: id, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
                return weather
                
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
```

WeatherModel:

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel {
    var conditionId: Int
    var cityName: String
    var temperature: Double
    
    var temperatureString: String {
        return String(format: "%.1f", temperature)
    }
    
    var conditionName: String {
        switch conditionId {
        case 200...232:
            return "cloud.bolt"
        case 300...321:
            return "cloud.drizzle"
        case 500...531:
            return "cloud.rain"
        case 600...622:
            return "cloud.snow"
        case 701...781:
            return "cloud.fog"
        case 800:
            return "sun.max"
        case 801...804:
            return "cloud.bolt"
        default:
            return "cloud"
        }
    }
    
}
```

WeatherData:

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let main: Main
    let weather: [Weather]
}

struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    let description: String
    let id: Int
}
```

ListView: (place where i want to display data)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View{
    

    @State var weatherMenager = WeatherManager()
    @State var city : String = ""
    
    @State var textFieldText : String = ""
    
    
    func getWeather(weather : WeatherModel){ // 
        
        print(weather.cityName) //works - print data in console
        print(weather.temperatureString)// works - print data in console
        
        self.city = weather.cityName
        
        print(city) // doesn't print data just like it's empty string
        
    }
.... more code which dont't really metter - just swiftui code
```

I have no idea what's wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of things that work against some of the principals of SwiftUI.

Most importantly, in your current code, you create a new `ListView` when you've gotten the weather back when you do this:

```
let listVC = ListView()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  listVC.getWeather(weather: weather)
}
```

This is *not the same instance* of `ListView` that you started with, so it will never show anything on the UI. Also, it relates to why the `print(city)` code doesn't work -- `city` is a `@State` variable which requires the view to be loaded to the hierarchy to work as expected. Since your `ListView` isn't actually loaded, property wrappers like that may behave in unexpected ways.

One way to address this is to convert your `WeatherManager` to an `ObservableObject` and then observe a `@Published` property that gets updated when the weather is returned. That may look like this:

```
class WeatherManager : ObservableObject { //<-- Conform to ObservableObject
    
    @Published var weatherModel : WeatherModel? //<-- @Published property to store the returned data
    
    let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=APP_ID&units=metric" //<-- Removed your App ID
    
    func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        print("Fetch weather: ",urlString)
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error",error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data, let weather = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.weatherModel = weather
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            let id = decodedData.weather[0].id
            let temp = decodedData.main.temp
            let name = decodedData.name
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId: id, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View{
    @StateObject var weatherManager = WeatherManager() //<-- Here
    @State var city : String = "Portland"
    @State var textFieldText : String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let weather = weatherManager.weatherModel {
                Text("Temp: \(weather.temperatureString)")
                Text("City: \(weather.cityName)")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: city)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is the smallest change to your code to make it workable. You may want to look into using `Combine`, for your URL task, which would be a most SwiftUI-centric way of loading the data. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/processing_url_session_data_task_results_with_combine

Also, you don't *need* the `ObservableObject` -- everything could be moved into a `Task` on your `View`. Personally, I like the separation of network requests into a separate object, but some feel that even this code belongs on the `View`.

Finally, although it doesn't relate directly to your issue, be careful with your city parameter in the URL -- you're not URL encoding it right now, so city names with spaces, for example, won't work as expected.